# Set cell format based on variable

Tags: excel, vba, format

I'm pretty new to VBA so I think this should hopefully be an easy answer, apologies if this sort of thing has already been asked or if it's super obvious!

I'm trying to set shading of a cell based on the value provided in another cell (specifically, the colours and shades to set either black or grey). I keep getting an error on the '.ThemeColor = thmclr' line. I think I have just inputted the 'thmclr' bit wrong. In cells I3 and I4 in 'Othersheet' are the correct colour codes for black and grey (depending on which one it is). Is anyone able to clarify how I should be doing this? Thanks!

```
Set thmclr = Worksheets("Othersheet").Range("I3")
Set tntshde = Worksheets("Othersheet").Range("I4")

With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = thmclr
    .TintAndShade = tntshde
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
```

Comment: Have you thought about conditional formatting?

Comment: After the cell is created, it is then copy / pasted by the user into a cell of their choice. So using conditional formatting would be more complicated. Surely there is a super simple answer to this? I managed to create a custom range using this method, so surely it is something similar -->

Set rnglkp = Worksheets("Othersheet").Range("I1") and then -->                  
    Range(rnglkp).Select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the values you are picking up from the cells correspond to valid *ThemeColors*:

```
xlThemeColorAccent1              5
xlThemeColorAccent2              6
xlThemeColorAccent3              7
xlThemeColorAccent4              8
xlThemeColorAccent5              9
xlThemeColorAccent6             10
xlThemeColorDark1                1
xlThemeColorDark2                3
xlThemeColorFollowedHyperlink   12
xlThemeColorHyperlink           11
xlThemeColorLight1               2
xlThemeColorLight2               4
```

Same for *TintAndShade*

**EDIT#1:**

For example, if we start with:

[image]

and run this code:

```
Sub cosmo()
Set thmclr = Worksheets("Othersheet").Range("I3")
Set tntshde = Worksheets("Othersheet").Range("I4")

With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = thmclr.Value
    .TintAndShade = tntshde.Value
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
End Sub
```

we get:

[image]

Note that the two controlling cells contain **NUMERIC** values.

Comment: I looked them up by recording a macro where I set the colour to black and then another where I set the colour to grey. The only two options for each one is - for themecolors: "xlThemeColorLight1" (Black) or "xlThemeColorDark1" (Grey) and for tintandshade: "0" (for black) and "-0.499984741" (for grey).

Comment: @cosmo  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: thanks for the edit. Though I have run this exactly as described and I get "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch', and the error is on the line     .ThemeColor = thmclr.Value - any ideas?

Comment: @cosmo not sure..............make sure the cell contains numeric **5** and not a text value that looks like a **5**

Comment: well the value in the cell is '5', and the formatting of the cell is as 'Number' if that's what you mean. The cell is a formula, so I changed it to just the number 5, and it still had the same error.

Comment: Ah, my mistake!! I had linked it to I3 when it was meant to be I4 as I've added a new row. My bad. Thanks for the answer :)